# Setting TTL/Record Expiry in hazelcast for individual entries without a put

Tags: hazelcast, hazelcast-imap

Is it possible to set ttl/record-expiry on an individual key ***without doing a put*** i.e, without changing the value of key. Something similar to **EXPIRE** in redis?
I can do a "get" followed by "put" and set the ttl but that would be in-efficient with large values.

```
hz = hazelcast.HazelcastClient()     
test_map = hz.get_map('test_map')
val = test_map.get(key) 
test_map.put(key, val, ttl)
```

Note - I am using hazelcast-python-client

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can adjust TTL with changing anything else with the map.setTtl() method:

```
IMap map = hz.getMap("testMap");   // get the map    
map.setTtl("keyToModify", 1, TimeUnit.HOURS);
```

Comment: Do we have an equivalent of setTtl in hazelcast-python-client? I don't see one in the documentation - https://hazelcast.github.io/hazelcast-python-client/3.12.3/hazelcast.proxy.map.html , thanks

Comment: Hi Ram, I'm not sure -- I don't see it in the docs, either, and it I couldn't find explicit mention of it in the Python client roadmap.   I've asked the developers for the Python client about it, and will let you know what I hear back.

Comment: This has been added as an issue for the Python client, see https://github.com/hazelcast/hazelcast-python-client/issues/214.   If you're interested in contributing, our team can work with you on the PR process - we are always happy to have community involvement on projects, and that's the quickest way to get this turned around.   Right now the Python team is focused on the 4.0 release, but with community assistance they could likely get a few small fixes or enhancements such as this turned around quickly.   If you have any additional notes on the issue, feel free to add them to the issue.